# Checksum example explanation in SQL Server (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone please explain me what does below query means?

I did not understand checksum in some links. It makes me confuse.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(StudentID, RegistrationDate)) 
FROM RegistrationSummary
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: The documentation has a far better explanation than I could come up with. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

Checksum computes an integer hash code from the columns given.   It is most often used to check whether the same values exist in two different tables, without having to go through the tedium of comparing each column one by one.

So, the query you've given is counting the number of rows in the table that have distinctive values for [StudentID] and [RegistrationDate].   Is the function equivalent of:

```
 SELECT Count(*) FROM
 (
    SELECT DISTINCT StudentID, RegistrationDate
      FROM RegistrationSummary
 )
```

Note that it is always possible for two completely different sets of values to end up having the exact same hash code, so this is not a perfect technique.   But this is pretty unlikely, given the way that the checksums are created, so it's a reasonably defensible approach for comparing data when a miscount of one in a billion or so is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, It's simply allowing 2 dissimilar data types to be concatenated to check for uniqueness  across the 2 columns.

You could just as easily rewrite it as...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(StudentID, RegistrationDate)) 
FROM RegistrationSummary;
```